# Angular how to add a button with a number greater than before?

Tags: angular, button, components, counter

I have a question, I cant solve that medium problem.

Here are some pictures:

[Picture how it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0Vgq.png)

[Picture how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xq7xt.png)

[Picture of how it shouldn't look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FLkt.png)

The main problem here is, that I need a counter for each button, but it can't be static due to the reason that it would affect each button.

Do you have any ideas how I have to proceed?

Here is what I got so far:

app.component.html

```
<div>
  <h2>By click on plus there should be added a new button with a new number</h2>
  <div class="item" *ngFor="let item of obj" (click)="addButton()">
    <span>{{item.id}}</span>
    <span>{{item['count'] ? item['count'] : item['count'] = 0}}</span>
    <button (click)="increment(item)">plus</button>
    <button (click)="decrement(item)">minus</button>
  </div>
</div>
<app-dialog></app-dialog>


<p>Add Button with different number</p>
<h2>{{counter}}</h2>

<div *ngFor="let button of buttons">
  <button (click)="addButton()">{{counter}}</button>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { isNgTemplate } from '@angular/compiler';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { ShareDataService } from './share-data.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  clickEventsubscription: Subscription

  id: number;
  title:String;

  obj = [{ id: 0, }, { title: 'test' }];

  constructor(private share: ShareDataService) {
    this.clickEventsubscription = this.share.getClickEvent().subscribe(() => {
      this.incrementCount(this.counter);
      this.addButton();
    })
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  counter: number = 0;
  incrementCount(counter: any) {
    this.counter++;
  }


  increment(item) {
    item.count++;
  }
  decrement(item) {
    item.count--;
  }

  buttons : {
    id    : number,
}[] = [{ id : 0}];

// Function to add new button
addButton(){
    this.buttons.push({
        id    : this.buttons.length,
    })
  }
}
```

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: If it's only an increment, why don't you use the index for the second `*ngFor` ? Like `<div *ngFor="let button of buttons; let i = index">
  <button (click)="addButton()">{{ i + 1 }}</button>
</div>`

Comment: Thank you for the answer I didn't think of that, very helpful. But I need the specific number of each button to work with it, for example adding a plus or minus button to adjust each button by their number. Do you have any idea how I can do that? The problem is that these buttons aren't created or shown yet, after clicking on that button they are getting created and so you can adjust each of them by their number, it's a bit tricky. But thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: My problem is solved, thank you again for your help and good luck for your life!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function incrementCount is incrementing the counter for all buttons:

```
incrementCount(counter: any) {
  this.counter++;
}
```

All of your buttons are linked to the same variable and as you increment this variable, the value of all buttons will increment simultaniously.

As Emilien said you could use a index in your `*ngFor`, if you want to increment always by 1.

You could also make use of an array where you fill the array with the numbers that you want on your buttons in the specific order, e.g.:

```
var counterArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...]
```

and then in incrementCount you simply push the next number to the array. And in your html you do:

```
<div *ngFor="let numb of counterArray ">
  <button (click)="addButton()">{{ numb }}</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and your time, I really appreciate it. That is closely want I needed! But I can't get it to work, that I can generate a button and at the same time increment the number of that button, so that I can keep working with it. The main idea is to adjust the number for example of button 3, do adjust it and play with it, for example adding 2 to it, so the other buttons don't get touched. The row would look like: ```1, 2, 5, 4, 5, 6....```. Thank you for your time again and I hope there is a way to do this.

Comment: Maybe like this?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-is4p1y?file=src/app/app.component.html

-> I only implemented the "increase button number", not the decreasing
-> click on one of the below buttons to add a new button
-> then increase the button number that you want to change with plus / minus
-> then click on "increase button number" to actually increase the number of that button
If you don't want the newly added buttons to always start with 0, you can try to pass a value in 'addButton(yourValue)' and then use it in 'this.counterArray.push(yourValue)'

Comment: Wow! Thank you a lot for your effort to create a stackblitz for me that helped me so much more, I wish I could give you something back for your help. That works perfect! Exactly like that! The only problem left is, how to increment the number of a button which is created after clicking the button you created. For example the first button is 1, the second is 2, the third one should be able to be increased or decreased, as well as the sixth or seventh button and so on, or is that even possible? If not, thanks for all your effort but I hope there could be a way, I'll keep trying!

Comment: Mhh, I think I don't understand the left problem. Let's say the first button is 1, the second button is 2, the third button is 5. Now to increase the value of the second button to 3 or 4, you just need to hit "plus" until the index says "01" and then click on "increse button number". The value of the second button should go up to 3. click again and it's 4...
(the index should be changed so that "02" changes the second button, not the third, I was just too quick to test everything, but that's easy to fix)

Comment: Ohhh I forgot about that to try it out, it really works. Thank you soo much Mr. Grg Kro for helping me out to solve that problem, which kept me busy for days. You are awesome, I wish you good luck in your life and hope that you will also help other people with your knowledge. God bless you.